# How to replicate a fieldset's legend style with a horizontal rule?

Tags: html, css

I want to put text in the middle of a horizontal rule, but have the text "break" the horizontal line but with a transparent background. Like this:

[image: Horizontal rule]

but with the line *not* going through the words.

Comment: ok, so here you go. Give both an absolute position, give the line a z-index of -1 and the text a z-index of +2 and voila. The other option is to have the text's div be the same width as the HR, then give the text a position relative with a -y value to pull it up. But that's sketchy.

Comment: You could not use a horizontal rule, but instead use a psuedo element before and after and have a border-top and adjust the position kind of like http://jsfiddle.net/zxzLT/22/.